# Kafka APIs for getting topic details like Partition and Offset

Tags: java, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have Node and Java applications uses Kafka clients.

Current requirement is to get the current offset for each partition for given topic.

We are able to see details in Confluent control center and need to get that information to display in our application.

Comment: For node... Find the README? https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka#reading-current-offsets-from-the-broker-for-a-topic

Answer (score 0):

You could call `KafkaConsumer.endOffsets(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` to get the end offsets of the given partitions for a given topic.